# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error not solved by -Xmx and -Xms

Tags: java

I'm beginner in java and I tried to make a code which sums two matrixes, but I have the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

I tried all this commands :

```
$ java Main
$ java Main -Xmx2048m
$ java Main -Xms1024m
$ java Main -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
$ java -Xmx2048m Main
$ java -Xms1024m Main
$ java -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m Main
```

But all give the same error message...

This is the code :

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int n = 10000;

        double A[][] = new double[n][n];
        double B[][] = new double[n][n];
        double S[][] = new double[n][n];

        int i,j;

        for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j<n; j++)
            {
                A[i][j] = 1.0d / ((double) i*j);
                B[i][j] = 1.0d / ((double) i*j);
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j<n; j++)
            {
                S[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, this code need ~ 3x8x10000 B = 240 000 B < 2048 MB.
My java's version :

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3,     mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: You are trying to initialize very huge 2-D array.
You can try with `n =100`.

Comment: Your code needs ~ 3 x 8 x 10000 *x 10000* B

Comment: I was able to run your program in my eclipse. But my machine has 16 GB RAM. With out setting -Xmx2048m and -Xms it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

The flags work, but your math does not check out.

You have `3` arrays, each with `10 000 * 10 000 * 8B` values.
For that you need `3 * 10 000 * 10 000 * 8 Bytes`... which is `2289 MB`.
That is already more than `2048`.

To add to that, each of those `3` arrays contains `10 000` references... but the memory overhead of that is minuscule (less than `1MB`) compared to the values.

Comment: Oh yes... I'm stupid --' (and I'im not computer scientist : I'im mathematician !) Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run your code without any Xms or Xmx setting. My Laptop is having 16 GB Ram.

[image]